# Can you Replicate a specific AWS ECR Repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, replication, amazon-ecr

To Devs,
Going through the AWS Console, you have the capability to replicate a Repo by setting up replication in the registry which affects all Repo's in the region.
I would like to setup specific replication based on the repo as in:
Repo (in diff regions)
Repo1           Repo1
Repo2           (no repo)

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible today with the current out of the box ECR replication experience but we are working on this. See [this GH issue on the AWS container roadmap](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1186). Feel free to +1 it (and optionally add your context). For future readers, that issue will be updated when the feature launches.

For completeness, you could always build an outside mechanism (outside of ECR that is) to replicate today a single repo but clearly this is not what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I am copying one image across ECR's via docker pull and push in the CD pipeline which I don't believe is as clean as at the repo level.

Comment: Yes that is the most common workaround. We want to remove that heavy lifting.